# Best way to synchronize local code with server

Tags: version-control, synchronization, repository, samba

I am looking for the most efficient way to synchronize local copy of code with a server in real time and hope it could automatically update changed files as soon as I save them on the local machine.

I am currently accessing remote resource via Samba but it is slow and almost unusable.
I do not edit files on the server so there is no need for comparing them with local copy.

**A little context:** I edited project on Windows using Eclipse as IDE. The server is running on Linux and I have used it to compile and run code. What I  need is the local copy of the program for quick searching in files and opening them. Then I will edit and save one of them. I would like it to automatically be uploaded to repository.

Currently I am using FreeFileSync with real time sync of only one small directory for speed but I hope that the solution could monitor the whole source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining it as a remote project that you connect to via SSH?  You can set up a project with a remote (SSH) source.  Setting Eclipse up to do this should be more efficient than going for a low-level solution.  Combining this with source code management should be helpful.  With any SCM (such as Git), you can commit code and instruct your server to pull changes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try it tomorrow at work.

Comment: I have tried remote project, but as it turned out synchronized project was a better solution. Still, thanks to you I am now able to work on local copy of code while having it synchronized with server immediately.